# Mount with sshfs in /etc/fstab file

Tags: fstab, sshfs

I am trying to connect to sshfs with fstab on Ubuntu, but the files are not loading.

In the fstab I put the following :

```
ssh2@192.1.1.1:/home/ssh2/SSHserver  /home/asir3/Escritorio/SSHclient  fuse.sshfs noauto,x systemd.automount,_netdev,user,idmap=user,follow_symlinks,identityfile=/home/ssh2/.ssh/id_rsa,allowother,default_permissions,uid=1001,gid=1001 0 0
```

Then I save and make a : `mount -a`

It doesn't give me any error, it lets me access the folder, but it doesn't synchronise with the server.

The server has the following content :

```
ssh2@Asir03:~$ tree SSHserver/
SSHserver/
├── ssh1
│   ├── 15.txt
│   ├── 1.txt
│   └── a
│       ├── 150.txt
│       └── 15.txt
├── ssh1.txt
├── ssh2
│   ├── pepa.txr
│   ├── pepa.txt
│   └── pepe.txt
├── ssh2.txt
└── ssh3
    ├── gema.txt
    ├── javi.txt
    ├── juan.txt
    └── marina.txt

4 directories, 13 files

ssh2@Asir03:~$
```

And this is what I get in the client:

```
asir3@Asir03:~/Escritorio$ tree SSHclient/
SSHclient/
└── hola

1 directory, 0 files

asir3@Asir03:~/Escritorio$
```

It lets me add folders, files and so on, but it doesn't save on the server.

Comment: you definitely also want to add `reconnect` to the options, or else your file system will become a complete hang-up if anything gets disconnected – be it because of your network connection, due to the server dropping your client, or any other reason. Still, sshfs is **not** something I'd recommend to have permanently mounted - any communication error results in half-written files and there's no way to know the state or recover from that. Really, just a "deploy this quickly" file system, not something you want to automount!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Any recommended alternatives to sshfs to mount remote directories ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`noauto` means "no automatic mounting", so that this file system is neither mounted at boot nor when doing `mount -a`. You can, however, as normal user mount it.

Comment: so if i replace by auto and do the mount -a ready?

Comment: if `mount /home/asir3/Escritorio/SSHclient` works right now, then yes

Comment: note that this will also mount things at boot, and that means if the remote server isn't reachable, your boot process might hang

Comment: I already knew that but it should be done in the fstab file as requested in the exercise in the previous question and I already mounted it and it worked. But thank you very much anyway.

Comment: I set it up like this : ``sshfs ssh2@192.1.1.1:/home/ssh2/SSHserver /home/asir3/Escritorio/SSHclient ``

Comment: yes as said, your fstab entry is correct if `mount /home/asir3/Escritorio/SSHclient` works. full stop!

Comment: True but the goal is to mount it in the fstab file, not that every time I want to do it I have to connect by hand with the mount.

Comment: we might be missing each others point. You asked "if I replace.. will it work" and I said "yes, if `mount /home/asir3/Escritorio/SSHclient` works now, then removing `noauto` will lead to `mount -a` succesfully mounting it"

Comment: now I get this :                                                                                        

asir3@Asir03:~$ sudo mount -a

fuse: mountpoint is not empty

fuse: if you are sure this is safe, use the 'nonempty' mount option

asir3@Asir03:~$

Comment: so, your mountpoint is not empty, and as said, `mount /home/asir3/Escritorio/SSHclient` would have told you this problem before.

Comment: now I get this : asir3@Asir03:~/Escritorio$ sudo mount -a

read: Connection reset by peer

Comment: yeah, that's your remote server rejecting your connection; that has nothing to do with your side, but probably the configuration of the remote server blocking your IP if you're not logging in with the right credentials, or anything else. Can't diagnose that!

Comment: and how do I fix it

Comment: If your remote SSH is not 100% reliable, SSHfs is a **terrible** choice. You *will* lose data if that happens during writing of a file.

Comment: Thanks but the only thing I want to do is to finish my ssh and sshfs exercises and this gives me a point for the exam.

Comment: I had the service turned off. I turned it on and ran sshfs in the fstab.